# Return 1st object from the array matching any value from input array using Java 8

Tags: java, arrays

I have a list of values `1,2,3,4`. It depends on my how I want to struct these values, be it `Array`, `ArrayList`, etc.

Then, I have the response coming from rest call which may or may not contain these values. My object is to return 1st object from the response's field4 which contains these values. The structure of response will be like below. In this case, I would like to return 2nd object from the array since 4 is the 1st match with given input.

```
{
    "field1": "",
    "field2": "null",
    "responseArray": [
        {
            "field3": "abc",
            "field4": "8",
            "field5": "def"
        },
        {
            "field3": "abc",
            "field4": "4",
            "field5": "def"
        },
        {
            "field3": "abc",
            "field4": "1",
            "field5": "def"
        }
    ]
}
```

I understand I can do brute-force method where I can traverse through each object of the response, then match field4 with given input values and once match is found, exit the loop so as to skip traversing rest of the loop. But, is there another effective way that can be used here specially with features from java8?

Comment: Have you got any code?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Set for your values, then something like this would work:
(assuming your responseArray is an array of objects that has a getField4 method)

```
Arrays.stream(responseArray).findFirst(e -> values.contains(e.getField4()));
```